# How can I access elements in the make_list() array in Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have a kusto query which summarize an array based on values in an `id column`.

The query is

```
Table
| where {some condition}
| extend d = parse_json(events)
| mv-expand d
| extend value=parse_json(d)["intValue"]
| project value, Id
| summarize make_list(value) by Id
```

The result is

| Id | value |
| --- | --- |
| ab8e | [1664379494002, 1664379485020, 1664379487998, 1664379473022] |
| 3dBc | [ 1664383366022,1664383372025, 1664381572017, 1664381566025] |

My question is can I do math operation in the array 'value'?
e.g. I want to `array[1] - array[0] + array[1] - array[2]` for each row?

Comment: Your code and question that not seem to make much sense.  Please share the whole scenario and not just the point where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can do that:

```
datatable(Id:string, value:dynamic)
[
    'ab8e', dynamic([1664379494002, 1664379485020, 1664379487998, 1664379473022]),
    '3dBc', dynamic([ 1664383366022,1664383372025, 1664381572017, 1664381566025]),
]
| extend result = tolong(value[1]) - tolong(value[0]) + tolong(value[1]) - tolong(value[2])
```

| Id | value | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ab8e | [1664379494002,1664379485020,1664379487998,1664379473022] | -11960 |
| 3dBc | [1664383366022,1664383372025,1664381572017,1664381566025] | 1806011 |